# 16.04.2 LTS - Error installing PHP trader extension with PECL

Tags: server, apache2, php7

PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4

```
$ pecl install trader
... 
Libraries have been installed in:
/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootdGbCc2/trader-0.4.0/modules
...
Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootdGbCc2/install-trader-0.4.0" install
...
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20151012/trader.so'
```

Ok, so up to this point, things seem to be going well.  Then I get the following errors:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/PackageFile/v2/Validator.php on line 870
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/PackageFile/v2/Validator.php on line 870

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/PackageFile/v2.php on line 1675
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/PackageFile/v2.php on line 1675

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/PackageFile/v2.php on line 1675
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/PackageFile/v2.php on line 1675
```

However, the output ends like this:

```
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/trader-0.4.0
Extension trader enabled in php.ini
```

I added `extension=trader.so` to my `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` and restarted apache, but the extension does not appear in `phpinfo()` or in `php -m`.  Attempting to execute any of the functions winds up with:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: It says `Extension trader enabled in php.ini` why then do u need to add it in `php.ini` again?

Comment: It was my understanding that it was a necessary step in the installation process.  However, I had already set the `apache2/php.ini` in the pecl config and there is only one instance of `extension=trader.so` in the ini, so I don't think it did any harm.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed this extension 3-4 times and have this issue each time. However I think I've figured it out. If the command

```
php -i | grep trader
```

Returns "Trader" then it's installed, but you won't be able to use it until php loads it via php.ini. You can check this running a phpinfo() function and looking for trader extension. If it's not there then you've likely added the extension=trader.so to the wrong php.ini file. Here is where it gets confusing. Running

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Tells you which php.ini file is loaded... However I found a total of 3 php.ini files in the php 7.4 directory > sub directories. So I added the line extension=trader.so to all the php.ini files I could find then restarted Apache and ran the phpinfo() function and trader was now loaded. Tested with some trader functions.

Note 1. Trader doesn't seem to work 100% in php 8.* Yet. The test showed some trader functions as failed.

Note2. You can also control precision and rounding for trader in your php.ini files too. Like at trader runtime for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a specific php.ini for CLI.

To test if the extension is on php CLI:

```
php -i | grep trader
```

To see which is the correct php.ini:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```